# Webapi Multipart formdata to accept Images and JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I tried to implement Webapi Action method which need to take Multipart formdata (Images and JSON Complex data). 
But the Json data which I am sending is coming as part of Formdata key value pairs instead of JSON and i couldn't parse it as a object.

I tried Advanced Rest client to test my API and below is sample request.

[image: Request sample in ARC]

Is there a way, to make the API Controller to accept both files and Complex JSON object in a single action method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. For that you have to convert file into Base 64 String. And than after add that string object to your model. so that you can get your data and file in base 64 format to your controller. and for that you don't need multipart/form-data.

Comment: This is an API exposed, ant the client would use a tool like ARC, to send file and JSON data together as shown in above screen shot. I afraid, that i can't use the solution you proposed..